# How to restrict a value based on status for a id with multiple records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Active |
| 1 | Inactive |
| 2 | Active |
| 3 | Inactive |
| 4 | Active |
| 4 | Inactive |

In the above table when id has multiple status, need only the records with status as Active along with the remaining records.

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Active |
| 2 | Active |
| 3 | Inactive |
| 4 | Active |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try, With an INDEX on [ID] and [Status] it would be quite fast

> ```
> SELECT [ID],[Status] FROM tabl1 WHERE [Status] = 'Active'
> UNION ALL
> SELECT [ID],[Status] FROM tabl1 t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tabl1 WHERE [Status] = 'Active' AND [ID] = t1.[ID])
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Status  
> -: | :-------
>  1 | Active  
>  2 | Active  
>  4 | Active  
>  3 | Inactive
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8001835250d384cd9e8c82c8de8b1fda)*